# Use a variable to refer to an item in a dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make a function that will receive an input from the user and use that input to delete an item from a dict. The input is assumed to be equivalent to a key. With the code below, I am intending that if `2` is input, then the item `2: "item_b"` will be deleted.

With what I have written, I receive a key error. Meanwhile, if I replace `i` in `thedict.pop(i)` with `2`, the code functions as intended. How do I make `thedict.pop(i)` read `i` as a variable?

```
thedict = {
1: "item_a",
2: "item_b",
3: "item_c"
}
while True:
    i = input("input: ")
    thedict.pop(i)
    print(thedict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns string while your keys are integers.
Try the following:

```
thedict = {
1: "item_a",
2: "item_b",
3: "item_c"
}
while True:
    i = input("input: ")
    // int() converts string to integer, 
    // The additional parameter suppresses error if the key is not present
    thedict.pop(int(i), None)
    print(thedict)
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` reads a string. Your keys are integers. So you need to convert the input to an integer, for example with `int(i)`.